# laravel query not returning values - strange pdo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, builder

I have come across a strange problem I am having, and it has really stumped me. I am using laravel to build my website and I have just written a script to act as a search engine. It is built and then run.

---

I am simply running the `$query->get()` with the `$query` being a laravel builder class. This is the query contents:

---

```
select * from (
    select `l`.*, round(
        d.distance_unit
        * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latitude))
        * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
        * COS(RADIANS(p.longitude - z.longitude))
        + SIN(RADIANS(p.latitude))
        * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))),
            2
    ) AS distance, `d`.`radius` from `listings` as `l` 
    inner join `horses` as `x` on `x`.`id` = `l`.`listing_id` 
    inner join `suburbs` as `z` on `z`.`id` = `l`.`suburb_id` 
    inner join (select 50 as radius, 111.045 as distance_unit) as d on 1 = 1 
    inner join `suburbs` as `p` on `p`.`id` = 1 
    where (
        `z`.`latitude` between 
            ? 
            and 
            ? 
        and `z`.`longitude` between 
            ? 
            and 
            ?
    )
) as sub 
where `distance` <= `radius` 
order by `created_at` desc 
limit 9 offset 0
```

The query bindings:

```
[bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression Object
            (
                [value:protected] => p.latitude  - (d.radius / d.distance_unit)
            )

        [1] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression Object
            (
                [value:protected] => p.latitude  + (d.radius / d.distance_unit)
            )

        [2] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression Object
            (
                [value:protected] => p.longitude - (d.radius / (d.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latitude))))
            )

        [3] => Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression Object
            (
                [value:protected] => p.longitude + (d.radius / (d.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latitude))))
            )

    )
```

That is the query being run by laravel. When I print the sql. but i cant for the life of me work out why it doesnt return a value when the sql i run in phpmyadmin does. (All I do is add the bindings to the question marks then run in phpmyadmin). Ive come to the conclusion that laravels PDO must be doing something differently or joining them differently. I am using the `DB::raw()` method for each of those values.

Comment: Try to print query through print_r(DB::getQueryLog()) see, what query is generating

Comment: laravel doesnt seem to print the exact query. the above content is what was retrieved from `DB::getQueryLog()`. It seems to only just display the query and the bindings seperately which is the biggest pain of my life. haha. I read into it. Its because of **PDO** class. It sends it to the sql server as query and bindings apparently. so its basically impossible to determine the query that has run... :/

Comment: I would suggest trying out **Clockwork**. You'll need to install the [composer package](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) and either a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clockwork/dmggabnehkmmfmdffgajcflpdjlnoemp) (which is my suggestion) or an [embeddable webapp version](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork-web). It will allow you to debug anything, including your SQL queries, and it displays the exact queries run against the database (not queries with "?" where bound data should be).

Comment: this sounds like a nice plugin. that would have saved a lot of timie. thanks for telling me about it. I shall look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find my problem by configuring the `my.ini` for the mysql server. I turned `general_log_file = "queries.log"` under `[mysqld]` **on**. Then running `SET global general_log = 1;` in **mysql**.

---

This showed me the problem with my query. The bindings were being inserted in quotation marks, even though I was using `DB::raw()` . So I just need to figure a way to remove them.

Comment: I changed `$query->whereBetween()` to `$query->whereRaw()` and just wrote the main code